# Why aren't changes in MySQL database being updated in WebMatrix Database viewer?

Tags: mysql, sql, webmatrix

I have MySQL running on my local machine. I have created several tables in MySQL workbench and connected WebMatrix to the MySQL DB. All the tables are present, however one of them does not contain any data (but it contains data in MySQL database). I have refreshed in Web Matrix, redone the connection string etc but the data does not display. When I try to run the SQL that populated the database in MySQL, inside of WebMatrix I receive this error from the Database Manager:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My SQL is too long to post here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your error give you a line number?

Comment: No it does not. It just has a dialog pop up from the Database Manager with those exact words in it. No option for extra details. The SQL runs successfully in MySQL and I can see the data. Could the number of rows be anything to do with it (about ~18000 rows)?

Answer (score 0):

Restarted MySQL service and refreshed in WebMatrix. Data is now present. Not sure what was causing the issues but is resolved.